# Use data from web-site in JavaScript extension for Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, plugins, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Google Chrome extension with JavaScript. I'm new to this language, but everything was fine till I understood that I need to use some data from the selected web-site (just 5 strings from one table, but they are usually updated) are for it. What is an easy way of parsing data from another site (I would like to update one of my files at the moment the plugin is installed)?

I know how to do it with Python -- BeautifulSoup and I know how to parse data from the same tab.
So I believe that my question is really easy and stupid, because there has to be smth as nice as BeautifulSoup in JavaScript or at least a way to include python script in my extension, though I  couldn't find it
I'm sure that my situation is not unique, so I will be very grateful if you could share githabs with extensions like mine

I tried to use XMLHttpRequest but it looked too difficult for my problem + maybe I did smth wrong, because "xhr.responseText" returned an empty string..

Comment: If that web site is opened in a browser tab, you can access it in your *content script*. Otherwise, XHR is the way to go. You can set its responseType to 'document' or parse the response with DOMParser and then just access the DOM, look for examples. Also make sure you have the necessary permissions in manifest.json, and that you make the request in a properly declared background script. Note, if that site populates itself in a script, you'll have to use an iframe/tab and a content script.

Comment: Consider adding [MCVE](/help/mcve) to make the question more answerable.